# block.super returns NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm learning Django and I have problems with templates.

I'm trying to add content to extended template.

Structure of my code:

```
base.html
category
     -- category_detail.html
     -- list_content.html
```

category_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    {{ category_name  }}
{% endblock %}

{% block description %}
    {{ category_description }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
    <a href="{% url 'charts:category_error_list' category_name %}" id="list-button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Error list</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Simple subpage with button. Button should redirect to another template, hovewer it gives me NoReverseMatch.

list_content.html (which is category_error_list defined in view)

```
{% extends 'category/category_detail.html' %}

{% block content %}
   {{ block.super }}
   <h1 class="page-header"> Some string</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is displaying "Some string" under button. (I know it should be done better with AJAX for example, but I want to learn the basics).

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^category/$', views.categories_list, name='categories'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name>\w+)/$', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name>\w+)/list/$', views.category_error_list, name='category_error_list'),
]
```

views.py

```
# ${url}/category/${category}
def category_detail(request, category_name):
    cat_detail = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
    return render(request, 'charts/category/category_detail.html',
                 {'category_name': cat_detail.name,
                 'category_description': cat_detail.description})

#${url}/category/${category}/list
def category_error_list(request, category_name):
    category_with_errors = Category.objects.filter(name=category_name)
    error_list = Error.objects.get(category=category_with_errors)
    return render(request, 'charts/category/list_content.html',
                 {'errors_list': error_list})
```

Problems seems to be related with `urls.py`, but I can't find what is wrong.

Stacktrace:

```
Template error:
In template                 
/usr/src/app/analizer/charts/templates/charts/category/list_content.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'category_error_list' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category_name>\\w+)/list/$']   
1 : {% extends 'category/category_detail.html' %}
2 : 
3 : {% block content %}
4 :    {{ block.super }}
5 :    <h1 class="page-header"> Cos tam </h1>
6 : {% endblock %}
7 : 
8 :
```

If I will remove `block.super` tag it is working, but I'm overriding content on parent template. What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Django-1.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution - which is nonintuitive for me - but it is working.

View `category_error_list` was missing `category_name` variable, so I have fixed it but this:

```
def category_error_list(request, category_name):
    category_with_errors = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
    error_list = Error.objects.get(category=category_with_errors)
    return render(request, 'charts/category/list_content.html',
                 {'category_name': category_with_errors.name,
                  'errors_list': error_list})
```